# npm i resulting in many ERESOLVE issues

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting this error on `npm i`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"4.41.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     dev babel-loader@"^8.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (copy-webpack-plugin, css-loader)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev mini-css-extract-plugin@"^0.9.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.44.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.4.0" from mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I get it when I downgrade nodejs to 14.15.4, but I may actually need to downgrade node.js.

Any idea how to interpret this issue and resolve it?

Comment: What version of npm are you using when you see this issue?

Comment: version @Trott 7.3.0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ERESOLVE` issues with `npm@7` are common because npm 7.x is more strict about certain things than npm 6.x. Often, the easiest resolution is to pass the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag to `npm` (e.g., `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`) or else use `npm@6`.

If that doesn't work immediately, perhaps try removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` first. They will be recreated.

(Tip: You don't need to uninstall `npm@7` to use `npm@6`. Use `npx` to specify the version of `npm` instead. For example: `npx -p npm@6 npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.)

Answer (score -1):

For npm v7+.
It is due to missing dependencies for entries mentioned in package.json file

use `npm i --force`, or `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` to override peer dependency.