# npm install error while use webpack, Could not resolve dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, leaflet, webpack-2

The error as follows:

```sh
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: webpack@3.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^3.5.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"2 || 3 || 4" from _babel-loader@7.1.5@babel-loader@7.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/_babel-loader@7.1.5@babel-loader
npm ERR!   5 more (_html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1@html-webpack-plugin, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^2.0.0" from _strip-pragma-loader@1.0.0@strip-pragma-loader@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/_strip-pragma-loader@1.0.0@strip-pragma-loader
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/agou-ops/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/agou-ops/.npm/_logs/2021-04-12T02_49_11_062Z-debug.log
```

`debug.log` file content:
[image]

packge version and system

- npm: 7.6.3
- webpack: 3.12.0
- system: Ubuntu 20.04

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 17):

`npm@7` has stricter dependency resolution than previous versions. If you can update the version of `webpack` in your root project, that may resolve it. An alternative easy quick thing to try is `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: If still not working, try with `--force` option. That is, `npm install --force`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

try to run the command with `--force` , if you don't use the related package.

e.g.

```
npm install --verbose --force
```

Answer (score 0):

For npm v7+. It is due to missing dependencies for entries mentioned in the package.json file

use:

> npm i --force

or

> npm i --legacy-peer-deps

to override peer dependency.
[Answered in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75171280/14011121)

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade to a lower npm version with, for example,

```
npm install npm@6
```